# fullpage.js is not able to scroll

Tags: html, jquery, fullpage.js

I want to add fullPage.js to my HTML website. But my page will not be able to scroll it the whole page just stuck at the content in the header tag and is not able to scroll to other sections. I tried to change the class name of each section to "section" but it doesn't work too. Below are my codes

My codes are below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.min.css"/>
</head>

<div id="fullPage">
<header>
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <div id="landingvideo" style="display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
    <iframe  class="landingpage"scrolling="no" style="width:4500px; height:1000px; border:none;" marginheight="100%" marginwidth="100%" src="landingpage.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
<iframe  class="minicarousel" src="minicarousel.php" frameborder="0" marginheight="100%" marginwidth="100%" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>

<body>
<section class="section_position" id="section0">
    <div class="container mb-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto text-center">
        <p id="title">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p id="des1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p id="des2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula arcu, venenatis at elit accumsan, tincidunt tempor ipsum. Maecenas risus sem, dignissim vitae velit vel, sodales pulvinar nibh. In vulputate felis et egestas ultricies. Praesent mollis erat turpis, ac faucibus orci ullamcorper nec. Aenean ac fermentum eros.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="carousel-wrap container mb-5">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <br/>
            <img src="images.png" class="img" style="width: 100%; height: 438px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <br/>
            <img src="images.png" class="img" style="width: 100%; height: 438px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <br/>
            <img src="images.png" class="img" style="width: 100%; height: 438px;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto text-center mb-5">
    <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html"><img src="images.png" ></a>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section_position mb-5" id="section1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto text-center">
      <p id="title">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p id="des1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p id="des2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula arcu, venenatis at elit accumsan, tincidunt tempor ipsum. Maecenas risus sem, dignissim vitae velit vel, sodales pulvinar nibh. In vulputate felis et egestas ultricies. Praesent mollis erat turpis, ac faucibus orci ullamcorper nec. Aenean ac fermentum eros.</p>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <center> <img class="icon1" src="images.png"> </center>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <center> <img class="icon1" src="images.png"> </center>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <center> <img class="icon1" src="images.png"> </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto text-center ">
        <a href="#contactme" ><img src="images.png" ></a>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="section_position mb-5" id="section2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto text-center">
        <p id="title">Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p id="des1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p id="des2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ligula arcu, venenatis at elit accumsan, tincidunt tempor ipsum. Maecenas risus sem, dignissim vitae velit vel, sodales pulvinar nibh. In vulputate felis et egestas ultricies. Praesent mollis erat turpis, ac faucibus orci ullamcorper nec. Aenean ac fermentum eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <video id="method" poster="imagespng" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" style="width: 100%;height: auto;">
                <source src="loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</br>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.9/fullpage.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new fullpage('#fullPage',{
        autoScrolling:true
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: A fair warning: jQuery is about the worst possible thing to use for both your work and your experience due to it's terrible performance and version-lock-in. You will gain little to no XP with the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<body>` is on the middle of your HTML...
You are writing HTML before the `<body>` tag (`<div id="fullPage">`) and so on.

So, short answer:

Check your HTML code. It is just not correct.